# relative routing in react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router

Did anyone know how to create  for any path that ends with '/popup-image-:id' ? i have website where each image could be opened in popup on any page. So, if i couldn't implement '/popup-image-:id' i have to double each route in my website to place  inside. I would like avoid redundance and fragility.
my current routing:

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
   <Route path="/" component={Base}>
      <Route path="profile" component={Profile}>
         <Route path="popup-image-:id" component={Full_Piture} />
      </Route>
      <Route path="feed" component={Feed_List}>
         <Route path="popup-image-:id" component={Full_Piture} />
      </Route>
      <Route path="user-:id" component={User_Page}>
         <Route path="popup-image-:id" component={Full_Piture} />
      </Route>      
   </Route>
</Router>
```

As u can see i had to produce a lot of duplicated code. If i could write something like `<Route path="*/popup-image-:id" component={Full_Piture} />` it will be much cleaner and solid code

Comment: Which react-router version are you using ?

Comment: npm info react-router version shows 3.0.0  
npm list --depth=0 shows react-router@2.8.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the parent `<Route>` also supposed to match? If it isn't, you should be able to use the [`**`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/RouteMatching.md#path-syntax) syntax.

```
<Route path="/**/popup-image-:id" component={Full_Picture} />
```

If the parent `<Route>` should also match, you could create a `<RouteWithPopup>` component that returns a `<Route>` which has the `<Route path='popup-image-:id'>` as its child.

```
const RouteWithPopup = (props) => {
  return (
    <Route {...props}>
      <Route path="popup-image-:id" component={Full_Picture} />
    </Route>
  )
}
```

Then you could turn your route config into:

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
  <Route path="/" component={Base}>
    <RouteWithPopup path="profile" component={Profile} />
    <RouteWithPopup path="feed" component={Feed_List} />
    <RouteWithPopup path="user-:id" component={User_Page} />
  </Route>
</Router>
```

Comment: Wow! that's works for me! Thanks! I'm very glad to have this solution
Buy the way maybe u know how to make all links for this path "/**/popup-image-:id" ? at the moment i use context location to get current path and attach "/popup-image-:id" in the end. But i get annoying warnings

Comment: React Router does not support relative locations in <Link>s so unfortunately you need to manually create the pathnames. What warnings are you getting?

Comment: Thanks for clarifications. About error: I use location pathname which i get from Router. Then i use <Provider /> component from mobx-react library. It propagate location pathname to any internal component that need it. So, error is "MobX Provider: Provided store 'location' has changed. Please avoid replacing stores as the change might not propagate to all children" is generated by Provider. I assume that problem is connected with mobx-react.

Comment: The warning you get is definitely from mobx-react. I'm not particularly familiar with mobx, but perhaps this https://github.com/alisd23/mobx-react-router will be useful.